# Email body cut off when using Send-Mailmessage using Powershell

Tags: powershell, email

So I have a PS script that I'm using to detect what display monitors are being used by a computer. The goal is to run these scripts remotely on clients' computers through an RMM service to get that information without contacting the client. In order to get the output, I want to send the information to myself through an email. I managed to get an email to send, but the body of the email gets cut off, compared to the output shown in Powershell. I'm using the $body variable to print to the command line and to the email body, so they should be the same, but they're not. Does anyone see anything wrong with my code (other than the email information being removed for privacy)?

[This is the output from the command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWERY.png)

[This is the output in the email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e26dJ.png)

```
$body = "Name, Serial"
function Decode {
    If ($args[0] -is [System.Array]) {
        [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString($args[0])
    }
    Else {
        "Not Found"
    }
}

ForEach ($Monitor in Get-WmiObject WmiMonitorID -Namespace root\wmi) {  
        $Name = Decode $Monitor.UserFriendlyName -notmatch 0
    $Serial = Decode $Monitor.SerialNumberID -notmatch 0

#       echo "$Name, $Serial"
    $body += "`n$Name, $Serial"
}

function Get-MonitorConnectionType ($connector){
    switch ($connector) {
            '-2' {'Uninitialized'} 
            '-1' {'Other'}
            0 {'VGA'}
            1 {'SVideo'}
            2 {'Composite'}
            3 {'Component'}
            4 {'DVI'}
            5 {'HDMI'}
            6 {'LVDS'}
            8 {'D_JPN'}
            9 {'SDI'}
            10 {'DisplayPort'}
            11 {'DisplayPort (Embedded)'}
            12 {'UDI'}
            13 {'UDI (Embedded)'}
            14 {'SD TV Dongle'}
            15 {'Miracast'}
            16 {'Indirect Wired'}
            '0x80000000,' {'Internal'}
            'SVIDEO,' {'SVideo (4/7 Pin)'}
            'COMPOSITE_VIDEO' {'RF'}
            'COMPONENT_VIDEO' {'RCA/BNC'}
            default {"Unknown($_)"}
    }
}

$connections = get-ciminstance -namespace root/wmi -classname WmiMonitorConnectionParams
$videooutput = $connections.videooutputtechnology
$body += "`nDetected $($connections.count) monitor(s) attached to this computer."
$body += "`nThe following monitor connection types may be in use:"
foreach ($output in $videooutput){
    $body += " $(get-monitorconnectiontype $output)"
}

$body += "`n"
write-host "$body"
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString "" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("", $secpasswd)
Send-Mailmessage -smtpServer "smtp.office365.com" -Credential $cred -Port 587 -from "" -to "" -subject "PS Email Test" -body $body  -UseSsl
```

Edit: I tried commenting out the [$body += "`n$Name, $Serial"] line and the email sends just fine if it skips that part. Cpt. Whale suggested it has to do with the ``n character, but it works just fine in the other places I used it. So I think something is just going wrong with the second iteration of the ForEach loop, but I don't have enough PS experience to know what it might be.
[Result with that line commented out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STTrY.png)

Comment: If you check your email in a text editor, do you see the body content just not displaying? A common issue is the result of html formatting not respecting `\`n`

Comment: I edited my question. So I don't see why it would be the ``n character because I use it in multiple lines and they display properly if I comment out [$body += "`n$Name, $Serial"] in the ForEach loop. It makes me think something goes wrong in the second iteration of the loop, but I don't know enough about powershell to know what it could be.

Answer (score 0):

All this considered. It is really prudent/valuable, that one step thru the code block as a single task to make sure you are getting what one would expect before moving to the next.

For example, stepping thru yours, using PowerShell variable squeezing to assign results to the variable, and output to the screen at the same time, in order to monitor real-time what is happening and being produced/passed (I did refactor your code a bit) :

```
function Decode 
{
    If ($args[0] -is [System.Array]) 
    {[System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString($args[0])}
    Else {'Not Found'}
}

function Get-MonitorConnectionType ($connector)
{
    switch ($connector) 
    {
            '-2' {'Uninitialized'} 
            '-1' {'Other'}
            0 {'VGA'}
            1 {'SVideo'}
            2 {'Composite'}
            3 {'Component'}
            4 {'DVI'}
            5 {'HDMI'}
            6 {'LVDS'}
            8 {'D_JPN'}
            9 {'SDI'}
            10 {'DisplayPort'}
            11 {'DisplayPort (Embedded)'}
            12 {'UDI'}
            13 {'UDI (Embedded)'}
            14 {'SD TV Dongle'}
            15 {'Miracast'}
            16 {'Indirect Wired'}
            '0x80000000,' {'Internal'}
            'SVIDEO,' {'SVideo (4/7 Pin)'}
            'COMPOSITE_VIDEO' {'RF'}
            'COMPONENT_VIDEO' {'RCA/BNC'}
            default {"Unknown($_)"}
    }
}

                        ($Body = ForEach ($Monitor in Get-WmiObject WmiMonitorID -Namespace root\wmi) 
{  
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name   = Decode $Monitor.UserFriendlyName -notmatch 0
        Serial = Decode $Monitor.SerialNumberID -notmatch 0
    }
})
# Results
<#
Name          Serial          
----          ------          
Not Found     0               
ASUS VE278    B7LMTF125646    
...  
#>


($connections = Get-CimInstance -namespace root/wmi -ClassName WmiMonitorConnectionParams)
# Results
<#
Active InstanceName                            VideoOutputTechnology PSComputerName
------ ------------                            --------------------- --------------
True DISPLAY\LEN4121\4&90cefb8&0&UID265988_0            2147483648               
...
#>

($videooutput = $connections.videooutputtechnology)
# Results
<#
2147483648
...
#>

$DataMessage = "
`nDetected $($connections.count) monitor(s) attached to this computer. 
The following monitor connection types may be in use:
"
($Body += $DataMessage)
# Results
<#
Name          Serial          
----          ------          
Not Found     0               
ASUS VE278    B7LMTF125646    
...        

Detected 4 monitor(s) attached to this computer. 
The following monitor connection types may be in use:
#>

foreach ($output in $videooutput)
{($Body += " $(Get-MonitorConnectionType $output)")}
# Results
<#
Name          Serial          
----          ------          
Not Found     0               
ASUS VE278    B7LMTF125646    
...         

Detected 4 monitor(s) attached to this computer. 
The following monitor connection types may be in use:
    Unknown(2147483648)
Not Found     0               
ASUS VE278    B7LMTF125646    
...         

Detected 4 monitor(s) attached to this computer. 
The following monitor connection types may be in use:
    Unknown(2147483648)
    DisplayPort
...  


Detected 4 monitor(s) attached to this computer. 
The following monitor connection types may be in use:
    Unknown(2147483648)
    DisplayPort
    ...    
...        

Detected 4 monitor(s) attached to this computer. 
The following monitor connection types may be in use:
    Unknown(2147483648)
    DisplayPort
    ...
#>


$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString '' -AsPlainText -Force
$cred      = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ('', $secpasswd)

$sendMailMessageSplat = @{
    From       = ''
    To         = ''
    Subject    = 'PS Email Test'
    Body       = $body
    Credential = $cred
    SmtpServer = 'smtp.office365.com'
    Port       = 587
    UseSsl     = $true
}
Send-MailMessage @sendMailMessageSplat
```

Are you certain that final outcome is what you were after, to be part of that email or a more finite version? Meaning that loop will duplicate stuff.

***Update by virtue of your error comment.***

Change to this to deal with that...

```
[string]$Message = foreach ($output in $videooutput)
{($Body += " $(Get-MonitorConnectionType $output)")}

$sendMailMessageSplat = @{
    From       = ''
    To         = ''
    Subject    = 'PS Email Test'
    Body       = $Message
    Credential = $cred
    SmtpServer = 'smtp.office365.com'
    Port       = 587
    UseSsl     = $true
}
Send-MailMessage @sendMailMessageSplat
```

Comment: I run your script and get this error: "Send-MailMessage : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'Body'. Specified method is 
not supported.
At C:\PS_Scripts\Monitor.ps1:140 char:18
+ Send-MailMessage @sendMailMessageSplat
+                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Send-MailMessage], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SendMailMessage"

Comment: Also, my original script doesn't duplicate anything, so I'm not sure why you added that "feature" to your solution.

Comment: Well, I did not test the Send-MailMessage stuff, so, well, ok, but as for adding any feature, I did not add anything. Yet, with a multi-monitor setup (mine includes a 4-port portable display port for that), you will get duplicate info (as per your for-loop 1 per each item in `$videooutput'). This on a single monitor setup will not.